Is long distance relation are haram? Will allah together us?
I'm muslim and im in a relationship with a Muslim girl. And our distance is too much.that's we we never meet each other. I know our distance was too much but our understanding was so perfect. I want to nikah with her after getting a job.But for this moment i have only 3-4 years.will allah together us?

Any intimate relationship with a non-mahram outside of marriage is haram. Be it long distance or short distance. We are not clairvoyant and so can not tell you whether you will end up together in the future or will break up with each other and never meet again.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note that in Islam a relationship between foreign people is haram there are legal ways to stay in contact before marriage for example an engagement, but even here a contact is limited.

assalam alaikom
it is haram (forbidden) to have a relationship with someone of the opposite sex before marriage,If you're serious about marriage, it's best to take the appropriate steps toward nikah (marriage) and avoid any haram actions in the meantime.
May Allah guide you and make things easy for you
